# Extracting related records from 2 columns in the same table using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I want to get the list of friends in the following query, but I'm getting an infinite loop, 
Here's my sample data:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Name nvarchar(50), Friends nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Joe','Jean'),
('Mike','Jean'),
('Jean','Zaki'),
('Zaki','Ali'),
('Mimi','Nana'),
('Mimi','Jean'),
('Chico','Yari')
```

and the query itself:

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT name rootname, t.* FROM @t t WHERE name = 'Joe'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT c.rootname, t.*
 FROM cte c
 JOIN @t t ON c.friends IN (t.name, t.friends) AND
              t.name NOT IN (c.rootname, c.name)
)
SELECT name FROM cte UNION SELECT friends FROM cte
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) One way:

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),';'+name+';') namelist, t.Name, t.friends 
 FROM @t t WHERE name = 'Joe'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),c.namelist+c.Friends+';'), 
        c.Friends, 
        case c.friends when t.name then t.friends else t.name end
 FROM cte c
 JOIN @t t 
   ON c.friends IN (t.name, t.friends) AND
      charindex(';'+case c.friends when t.name then t.friends else t.name end+';', 
                c.namelist)=0
)
SELECT name FROM cte UNION SELECT friends FROM cte
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79ff8/38).

Comment: @user2948058: Try with `option (maxrecursion 0)` (as amended, above) - this isn't necessary with the test data supplied, but may be necessary if you are running against a larger dataset.

Comment: Thank u, I tried it, with the exemple below, but i takes more than 16 minutes without any result.

Comment: @user2948058: How large is `@t`? What happens after 16 minutes?

Comment: @t is 10 rows, and nothing it's an endless loop

Comment: did u try your proposition?

Comment: @Talal: What proposition? The data supplied in your question runs in 0.043 of a second on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79ff8/29 . If your whole dataset is only 10 records long, why not add that to the question, or to another SQLFiddle?

Comment: I'm new to the website, please forgive me, I try to change my request.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table (Name nvarchar(50), Friends nvarchar(50))
insert into @T values 
('Joe','Jean'),
('Mike','Jean'),
('Jean','Zaki'),
('Zaki','Ali'),
('Mimi','Nana'),
('Chico','Yari'),
('Joe','Yari'),
('Mimi','Jean'),
('Mimi','Zaki'),
('Chico','Jean')

SELECT DISTINCT Name , STUFF(Flist, 1, 2, '') AS FriendsList
FROM @T t CROSS APPLY (
                       SELECT ', ' + Friends [text()]
                       FROM @T t2
                       WHERE t2.name = t.name
                       FOR XML PATH('')
                      )L(Flist)
```

This will give you list of all the friends for each name like this ..

**Result Set**

```
Name    FriendsList
Chico   Yari, Jean
Jean    Zaki
Joe     Jean, Yari
Mike    Jean
Mimi    Nana, Jean, Zaki
Zaki    Ali
```

Comment: Thank u sir for ur kind reply, but the friends of 'Joe' must be also friend of Mike and Zaki and ali...I don't know if u see what i mean.

Comment: Not a problem pal, if this is what you were looking for then you can accept the answer only use english here :)

Comment: Dear Mr Ali, the expected result for Joe's friends is  (Jean,Mike,Zaki,Ali), instead of of (Jean, Yari), as it results from your proposition, because it must show also the indirect friends. Thank u again